# how to implement websocket in vaadin with spring boot,spring security application

Tags: websocket, vaadin

I am developing web application using springboot, Spring security and  vaadin. In my application I am going to implement websocket to get the content from the server. Please guide me how to implement websocket in my application.

Comment: If you wish to develop a websockets part of your app you can do it just as you did always. This has nothing to do with vaadin

Comment: Like Andre, I'm bit unsure if you want to used WebSocket based communication in your Vaadin application or access another service with WebSocket?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems vague. If you're going to connect to a websocket server, you may use [Grizzly](https://grizzly.java.net/nonav/websockets.html) to do so. If you're intending to be a websocket server, you may use [Spring Websocket Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html) for that. In either case, Vaadin has no use.